# how to select next n letters after one specific letter using function in sql server by giving function name,specific letter, no of letters next

Tags: sql-server

how to select next n letters after one specific letter using function in sql server by giving function name,specific word, no of letters next to be printed

for eg : function name, ' specific letter', no of letters to be printed next to specific letter

Comment: first instance of letter or you want all instances ?

Comment: `substring()` might help.

Comment: Please tag only the database you are using. Either MySQL or MS SQL Server.

Comment: as like "Functionname, 'specificletter', no of letters to be printed next after c.

Comment: @BlindSniper need specific instance of letter and after that no of letters to be choosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create function new(@text varchar(50),@CharToSearch char,@CharactersToRetrieve int)

Returns varchar(100)

AS

BEGIN

```
DECLARE @new varchar(20)
DECLARE @CharToSearchs int
select @CharToSearchs= CHARINDEX(@CharToSearch, @text);
set @new=SUBSTRING(@text,@CharToSearchs+1,@CharactersToRetrieve)
RETURN @new
```

END

Answer (score 0):

Mixture of `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING` if on SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(100) = 'The cat is under the table.'

DECLARE @CharToSearch CHAR = 's'
DECLARE @CharactersToRetrieve INT = 5

SELECT
    CharacterPosition = CHARINDEX(@CharToSearch, @Text),
    TrimmedString = SUBSTRING(
        @Text,
        CHARINDEX(@CharToSearch, @Text) + 1,
        @CharactersToRetrieve)
```

Result:

```
CharacterPosition   TrimmedString
10                   unde
```

Comment: for eg : function name, ' specific letter', no of letters to be printed next to specific letter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL try the following query

```
select substring(user_name,locate("a",user_name)+1,2) from user_details where user_id=3;
```

In the above query, I am trying to fetch 2 letters after first occurrence of the letter 'a' from `user_name` field of my `user_details` table where `user_id` is 3.

Modify the query as per your need.